# How to call ComponentDidMount() of different component from another component in react.js

Tags: reactjs

Api.js

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import './Api.scss';
    import ProfileCard from 'components/Card/ProfileCard.jsx';
    import Modal from 'react-awesome-modal';

    class Api extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                title : '',
                content: '',
                img: '',
                data: []

            }
        }

        OnFileChange = (event) => {
            this.setState({img: event.target.files[0]});
        }

        onTitleChange = (event) => {
            this.setState({title: event.target.value})
        }

        onContentChange = (event) => {
            this.setState({content: event.target.value})
        }

        resetForm = () => {
            document.getElementById('title').value = '';
            document.getElementById('content').value = '';
            document.getElementById('img').value = '';
        }

        openModal() {
            this.setState({
                visible : true
            });
        }

        closeModal() {
            this.setState({
                visible : false
            });
        } 


        componentDidMount() {
            fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_profile/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(res => this.setState({ data: res }));  
        }


        SubmitProfile = (event) => {
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('img',this.state.img);
            formData.append('title',this.state.title);
            formData.append('content',this.state.content);
            fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/post_profile/', {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
                },
                body:formData,
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(res => {
                if (res.code === 200){
                    this.componentDidMount()
                    this.resetForm()
                    this.closeModal()
                }
                console.log(res);
            })
        }


        elasticSearch = (event) => {
            fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/', {
                method: 'post',
                headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    q: event.target.value 
                })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            this.setState({ data: res })
        });  
        }





        render(){
            return (
                <div className="api-body">
                    <section>
                        <div className="tc pa2">
                            <input
                                type="button"
                                className="br2 center ph3 pv2 input-reset ba b--black bg-transparent grow pointer f6 dib"
                                value="Post"
                                onClick={() => this.openModal()} 
                            />
                            <input
                                className="db ma3 q center border-box hover-black w-100 measure ba b--black-20 pa2 br2 mb2"
                                type="text"
                                name="q"
                                id="q"
                                placeholder="search here .."
                                onChange = {this.elasticSearch}
                            />
                            </div>
                            <Modal 
                                visible={this.state.visible}
                                width="400"
                                height="300"
                                effect="fadeInDown"
                                onClickAway={() => this.closeModal()}
                            >
                            <div className="mv3 pa3">

                            <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6" htmlFor="password">Title</label>
                            <input
                                className="db border-box hover-black w-100 measure ba b--black-20 pa2 br2 mb2"
                                type="text"
                                name="title"
                                id="title"
                                onChange={this.onTitleChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="mv3 pa3 mt-1">
                            <label htmlFor="comment" className="f6 b db mb2">Contents </label>
                            <textarea 
                                id="content" 
                                name="content" 
                                className="db border-box hover-black w-100 measure ba b--black-20 pa2 br2 mb2" 
                                aria-describedby="content-desc"
                                onChange={this.onContentChange}>
                            </textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div className="mv3 pa3 mt-1">
                        <input
                            type="file"
                            multiple = {false}
                            id="img"
                            name="img"
                            ref={(input) => { this.inpuElement = input; }}
                            accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.pdf,.doc"
                            onChange={this.OnFileChange}
                            />
                        <input
                            type="button"
                            className="br2 center ph3 pv2 input-reset ba b--black bg-transparent grow pointer f6 dib"
                            value="Submit"
                            onClick={this.SubmitProfile} 
                            />
                        </div>
                        </Modal>
                    </section>

                <ProfileCard data={this.state.data} />
                </div>
            )
        }
    }


    export default Api;
```

ProfileCard.js

```js
    import React from 'react';


    class ProfileCard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
        data : []
        }
    }

    deleteProfile = id => e => {
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/delete_profile/', {
        method: 'post',
        headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
            id: id
        })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(res => {
            if (res.code === 200){
            this.componentDidMount()
            }
            console.log(res)
        })
    } 

    render(){
    return (
        <div>
        {
        this.props.data.map((user,i) => {
            return (
            <article className='mw5 tc bg-white dib br3 pa3 ma3 pa4-ns mv3 ba b--black-10 shadow-5 pc-scroll pointer' key={i}>
            <div className="tc">

            <img 
                src={"http://127.0.0.1:8000" + user.photo}
                className="br-100 h3 w3 dib" 
                alt="profile pic"
                onDoubleClick = {this.deleteProfile(user.id)}
            />
                <h1 className="f4">{user.title}</h1>
                <hr className="mw3 bb bw1 b--black-10" />
            </div>
            <p className="lh-copy measure center f6 black-70">
            {user.content}
            </p>
            </article>
            );
        })
        }
        </div>
    );
    }
    }


    export default ProfileCard;
```

in my  ProfileCard there is a function deleteProfile as you can see and my componentDidMount
is on Api component. I want to call componentDidMount immediately  after deleteProfile executes.

I am not able to find any proper way to do this.
if i will send componentDidMount directly also it won't work
because i am assigning res into the state.

Comment: You have XY problem. You don't have to call componentDidMount directly. Please, explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: using componentDidMount() i am displaying all records. and after delete one also again i wants to display updated result so i am doing this way

Comment: Instead of calling `componentDidMount` you should call a `fetchProfileData` method. Then both `componentDidMount` and `deleteProfile` can call that method. Or, just have the API return the updated list in response to the delete call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@estus` is correct in the comments. You shouldn't - and don't - need to call `componentDidMount` directly but you can call a function from the owner component.

First, we create a new function for fetching the profile. This can still be called in `componentDidMount`.

```
fetchProfile() {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_profile/')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(res => this.setState({ data: res }));
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchProfile()
}
```

We then pass this function as a `prop` into `<ProfileCard />`

```
<ProfileCard data={ this.state.data } onProfileDelete={ () => this.fetchProfile() } />
```

Finally, we call this `prop` after we've deleted a profile within `ProfileCard`.

```
deleteProfile = id => e => {
        ...
        .then(res => {
            if (res.code === 200) {
                const { onProfileDelete } = this.props
                onProfileDelete() // call prop func instead
            }
            console.log(res)
        })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`componentDidMount` is lifecycle hook. It isn't expected to be called directly. A semantically correct way is to provide a method that will be reused in both places:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchData();
}

fetchData() {
    return fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_profile/')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(res => this.setState({ data: res }));  
}


SubmitProfile = (event) => {
    ...
    .then(res => {
        if (res.code === 200){
            return this.fetchData()
    ...
}
```

This also benefits testability. `fetchData` can be tested separately from component lifecycle. Also, methods should return promises, all promises should be chained.

The problem here is the separation of concerns. `ProfileCard` should be [dumb component](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) and delegate all the work to a parent. This method belongs to parent `Api` component:

```
deleteProfile = id => {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/delete_profile/', ...)
    ...
    .then(res => {
        if (res.code === 200){
            this.fetchData()
        }
    })
}
```

It should be passed to child component:

```
<ProfileCard onDelete={this.deleteProfile} />
```

And used in child component as a prop:

```
<img 
    src={"http://127.0.0.1:8000" + user.photo}
    className="br-100 h3 w3 dib" 
    alt="profile pic"
    onDoubleClick={() => this.props.onDelete(user.id)}
/>
```